# I can't get multiple live plots working at the same time in Matplotlib - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, live-streaming

```
jsontime = [-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0]
f, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax1 = axarr[0, 0]
ax2 = axarr[0, 1]

def tempa_plot():
    jsontempa = []
    ay=[]
    for k in range(100):
        jsontempaval = random.randint(30, 80)
        jsontempa.append(jsontempaval)
        print(len(jsontempa))

    for i in jsontempa:
        ay.append(i)
        if len(ay) > 10:
            ay.pop(0)
            ax1.ylim(30, 80)  # Set y min and max values
            ax1.xlim(-9, 1)
            ax1.title('Live Streaming Sensor Data: Temperature')
            ax1.grid(True)
            ax1.ylabel('Temp C')  # Set ylabels
            ax1.xlabel('Time')
            ax1.plot(jsontime,ay,label='Degrees C')
            ax1.legend(loc='upper left')  # plot the legend
            ax1.pause(0.2)
            ax1.clf()
            ax1.set_title('Axis [0,0]')

def tempb_plot():
    jsontempb = []
    by=[]
    for k in range(100):
        jsontempaval = random.randint(50, 100)
        jsontempb.append(jsontempaval)
        print(len(jsontempb))

    for i in jsontempb:
        by.append(i)

        if len(by) > 10:
            by.pop(0)
            print(by)
            ax2.ylim(45, 105)  # Set y min and max values
            ax2.xlim(-9, 1)
            ax2.title('Live Streaming Sensor Data: Temperature b')
            ax2.grid(True)
            ax2.ylabel('Temp C')  # Set ylabels
            ax2.xlabel('Time')

            ax2.plot(jsontime,by,label='Degrees C')
            ax2.legend(loc='upper left')  # plot the legend
            ax2.pause(0.2)
            ax2.clf()
            axarr[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0,0]')


tempa_plot()
tempb_plot()
```

This throws an error of axes not being subscript-able. 
I have a constant stream of data from my Arduino. Should I try multi-threading? Is there an easier and more efficient way of doing this? I tried running from different programs and that works perfectly fine.
TIA

Answer (score 1):

`plt.subplots(1, 1)` creates a 1 by 1 grid of subplots, i.e. there is only one plot. Thus the returned object is the axes themselves, not in an array. I suspect you're looking for either `plt.subplots(1, 2)` or `plt.subplots(2, 1)`, depending on how you want the axes oriented.

Also, once you fix that, you'll find there are other errors in your code. You seem to be mixing up some of the function names from `matplotlib.pyplot` (`plt`) with methods on axes objects. For example, to set the y-limit you can use `plt.ylim(...)` or `axes.set_ylim(...)`, but not `axes.ylim(...)`. I think you'll have this problem when trying to set the `ylim`, `xlim`, `title`, `xlabel`, and `ylabel`, all of which is fixable by simply adding `set_...` to the front of each property, if I recall correctly.

Edit:
Also, I just noticed you set the title on each axes twice, the first time incorrectly and the second time correctly; you probably only want to so this once. Also not sure what's going on with the `clf` and `pause` calls (both of which need to be to `plt` by the way, not an axes object). You should just do `plt.show()` after calling both your functions.

Comment: Thank! I am using pause and clf for interactive plotting